# Home page showing as only a trailing slash in analytics

Tags: google-analytics

My hompepage / index page is showing only as a trailing slash in my google analytics

[image]

Now if I did not know any better I would say *this is an indication that their is a miss configuration with a 301 on htaccess or canonical on the index page?* Or is this not necesarily the case.

My preffered version is www.example.com with a 301 setup from http://example.com
and in my index page I have   `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com." />`

**MY QUESTION**

Is this trailing slash which shows for the home page a possible sign of miss configuration on my part?

Thanks for taking the time to read

Comment: No. That is completely normal. It is something like the request for example.com being appended with a / as part of the standards. The / in GA is a request without index.html or any other file name.

Comment: You got it!! Thanks! BTW- This is a fantastic group. Come back with any questions you may have anytime. Many of us are here every day and we have some real experts- believe me! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That is completely normal.

It is something like the request for example.com being appended with an / as part of the standards. Browsers add the / to the request if the original request is `http://www.example.com` (URL) without a file path and/or resource (URI). It is simply completing the request with the minimum assuming that a default document is what is required by the user.

The / in GA is simply a request without index.html or any other file name.